# MySQL query that selects record based on todays date between date range set in record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `exhibitions` which has 2 columns `startDate` and `endDate`.  I want to select the records based on today's date.  So if today is '2012-05-24', I would want the record that's `startDate` would be '2012-05-01' and `endDate` would be '2012-05-31'.

I have used the query in reverse, find records between '2012-05-01' and '2012-05-31', but not based on today's date. Any direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select *
FROM exhibitions 
WHERE startDate < CURRENT_DATE() and endDate > CURRENT_DATE()
```

**UPDATE:**

You need to find the first day of the month and last day of the month. There is a LAST_DAY() function but no FIRST_DAY() function.

To find the **first day** of the month based on today's date you can use:

```
DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

To find the **last day** of the month based on today's date you can use:

```
 LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
```

The end query would be like this:

```
Select *
FROM exhibitions 
WHERE Startdate = LAST_DAY(CURRENT_DATE())
AND
endDate = DATE_ADD(LAST_DAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.  The question is how to get the first and last day of the current month to use as `startDate, endDate`

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `exhibitions` WHERE `startDate` < CURRENT_DATE() AND `endDate` > CURRENT_DATE()";

Comment: Actually the first query was almost there.  The startDate may not necessarily be the first of the month, and the endDate may not be the last day of the month.  The user will manually input the startDate and endDate.  So the above query worked perfectly.  Thanks again!

Comment: If it helped, you may want to consider: a) an upvote b) selecting my answer as a right answer. Thanks :o)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM exhibitions
WHERE startDate > DATE_FORMAT(CONCAT(SUBSTR(NOW(),1,8),'01'),'%a')
AND endDate < DATE_FORMAT(LAST_DAY(NOW()),'%a')
```